# Firebase push notification badge count is not being received in IOS app

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification with firebase from nodejs server.

the message payload is like this.

```
const notificationObjNew: any = {
        notification: {
            body: "demo body",
            title: "demo title",
            badge : "100",
        },
        topic: notificationTopic
    };
```

In IOS app I received this as-

```
{body:demo body,e:1,title:demo title}
```

Here is no badge property.

Answer (score 5):

IOS receives badge count under `aps` key. You probably sharing JSON of alert itself which is under `aps` as well.

Normal Payload

```
"aps" : {
      "alert" : {
         "title" : "Game Request",
         "subtitle" : "Five Card Draw",
         "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
      }
   }
```

with `badge`

```
"aps" : {
      "alert" : {
         "title" : "Game Request",
         "subtitle" : "Five Card Draw",
         "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
      },
      "badge":9
   }
```

Comment: This way, all the manipulations are from server side... The backend has to keep track of notification count.. There must be a better workaround such that the frontend side has the control of their badge count...